# Question about linear operator defined in C[0,1].

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm trying to solve the following exercise:

**Let be $X=C([0,1])$. We define $T:X \longrightarrow X$ as $T(f)(x)=\displaystyle \int_{0}^{x} f(t^2)dt$. Prove that $T^{-1} : T(X) \longrightarrow X$ is not continuous.**

I have proved that $T$ is a linear operator, continuous and injective, but I don't know how to prove that $T^{-1}$ is not continuous. In other exercises, people show that $||T^{-1}||$ is not bounded, but I think this is not useful in this exercise.

In X, I am considering the uniform norm (the max-norm).

Comment: Look at the norms of the images of the norm-1 functions $f_n$, where $f_n$ is the function whose graph consists of the two line segments connecting the points $(0,1)$,  $(1/n,0)$, and $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Solve $Tf=g$ by differentiating both sides to get $T^{-1}(g)=g'(\sqrt x)$. [This is defined on the range of $T$ which is the whole of $C[0,1]$).
Suppose there exists $C \in [0,\infty)$ such that $|T^{-1} g(x) | \leq C \|g\|$ for all $g$ for all $x$. Take $g_n(x)=\frac {x^{n}} {\sqrt n}$ to get a contradiction. [The inequality fails when $x=1$ and $n$ is large].